# How to do an API call via R using the Rcurl package when data is send back

Tags: r, api, rcurl

How can the following api statement be translated into code that I can run in R:

> curl \ -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \ -H
>   "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN" \ --data "{'query':'and for
>   tomorrow', 'timezone':'GMT-5', 'lang':'en', 'contexts':[{ 'name':
>   'weather', 'parameters':{'city': 'London'}, 'lifspan': 4}],
>   'sessionId':'1234567890'}" \ "https://api.api.ai/v1/query?v=20150910"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should know that SO is not a free code writing/translating service, you need to show your efforts.

Comment: Have a look at the `httr` package